# adb "Permission denied" to run a "./configure" file

Tags: adb, sd-card, shell, file-permissions, bash

I need to run a `configure` file into my android phone so I think the best way to do this is to use the `adb shell` command.

I'm running an Android emulator onto a Windows-7 platform, and there I'm running the `adb shell` command into a DOS window. Using the `cd` command I'm changing to the directory where my `configure` file is, and then I'm executing the following command: `./configure`. I'm getting the following error :

```
./configure: permission denied
```

So I try to run adb in root mode with `adb root` -- but apparently my adb is already in root mode (Moreover I have the "#" character before each line of my adb shell).

I have also tried to use `chmod` but I don't see any difference before and after executing this command (`ls -la`), so maybe the problem is here (How can I run the `chmod` command?).

Maybe someone here can help me with my issue, and if you have also an explanation about why I don't have the permission to run my `configure` file it will be great.

Thanks.

PS: My goal here is to use the net-snmp package on an Android platform by compiling the sources of this project directly onto the platform.

Comment: Where on the Android emulator's filesystem is the configure file? i.e. what's the path to the file?

Comment: The path of the file is /sdcard/net-snmp-5.7.2/configure

Comment: `chmod 0777 ./configure` try that, then try executing.

Comment: That's probably the problem. `/sdcard` is typically mounted with the `noexec` flag in Android, so you can't execute binaries from it. I would recommend trying to move it to somewhere else (often `/data/local` is used for things like that). See if that solves the problem.

Comment: Also, copy it to the `/usr/local/tmp` directory (the entire `net-snmp-5.7.2` directory in `/sdcard`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but it doesn't work. Before chmod 0777 : "----rwxr-x [...] configure" and after chmod 0777 : "----rwxr-x [...] configure". This is why I'm saying that maybe my problem is on "chmod" command.

Comment: @grattmandu03 Its because its on the SD card - sdcards dont support file permissions :)

Comment: Ok right. So I have tried to copy the net-snmp directory into /data/local/tmp then I have directly tried to run my configure file but I get a permission denied. So I'm using the "chmod 0777" command. And now I have something weird, when I'm running again my configure file I'm getting "file not found" but I still can see this file into the /data/local/tmp directory. What I'm doing wrong ??

Comment: what is the contents of `configure` script? Its looking for a file to execute.... Are you sure you know what you are doing? What is `configure` for? These details are missing from the question! :)

Comment: The "configure" file is the configure script provided by the net-snmp sources package. I'm trying to port the net-snmp package into an Android phone. For now I'm using the busybox script to run the configure script and it seems to work (I have just some errors due to a linux system is not like an Android system, but this what I'm looking for). Thanks to all of you.

Comment: Build it on the linux box, not on android.... you should have stated that from the start! :)

Comment: Yes I have done that, but I think that the architecture between a linux system and an Android phone is different so I cannot use the Linux result directly into my Android phone. By the way, I know there is some java librairies to use net-snmp, but my boss wants to have the net-snmp original source compiled onto an Android platform.

Comment: keywords *cross-compile* on linux targetting the ARM chipset support...

Comment: As it stands right now and transpires, this is rather a development question! Voting to close as this is off-topic.

Comment: @t0mm13b Not entirely sure if this *is* off topic, as it could be useful for people that need to execute a file on their device, such as a root exploit.

Comment: @LiamW clearly, the OP was trying to build on top of Android by running a development related `configure` script and taking the wrong approach altogether!

Comment: Ok thanks. My question here was more about how can I run a script sh with the adb shell than a development question. But now I have the solution : "/sdcard is mounted with the noexec flag", so if eldarerathis or Liam W wants to put their comment into a real answer I will validate it. Or maybe you can explained me how can I close my question?

Comment: @grattmandu03 I already have ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is due to 2 things:

1. The file does not have execute permissions [AND]
2. The file cannot gain executable permissions as it is on the SD Card. The SD Card's filesystem can accept file permissions, however it is mounted with the `noexec` flag, as stated in a comment. This stops files being executed.

Solution:

1. Copy the `net-snmp-5.7.2` directory to the `/data/local/tmp` directory as root.
2. Set the `configure` file to be executable by running `chmod 0777 /data/local/tmp/net-snmp-5.7.2/configure` as root.
3. You should now be able to execute the configure script by typing `/data/local/tmp/net-snmp-5.7.2/configure` and pressing enter.

**Note**

This should all be done as the root user :)

Comment: I get: /system/bin/sh: /data/local.../filename: No such file or directory.

Answer (score 10):

As explained by the comments and [Liam's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/35667/16575), this is due to the `noexec` flag used by the system when mounting the sdcard. If your `configure` file is a shell script (as it usually is), you can still trick it to be executed:

`cd` to the directory as you described above, and then execute `sh configure`.

`sh` is the Shell interpreter, and that binary should be located in `/system/bin`, where files *are* executable. Passing your script as the first argument, this will open a new shell process which executes your `configure` script.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The `sh configure` does the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! And glad I was able to help. I use this trick on Linux/Unix machines from time to time :)